# Developing custom drivers for proprietary hardware to access Serial Port on Metro/Modern App. What are the possibilities?

Tags: wpf, serial-port, windows-8.1, drivers

I asked a question previously and got some great answers. However since then, I've learnt a lot about the problem and now have a clearer idea of what the problem is (I'm not the tech lead, but I have a decent idea of the problems and tech in general).

To cut a long story short, we've developed a data collection app on Metro/Modern in the windows store environment for our sensor hardware (gps plus other sensors. sends data wirelessly, etc.). However two things I need to make clear is;

1. We have no intention to bring it to the windows store, but to sideload into necessary tablets. I've been told we'll need some enterprise license or some such, still not clear on this.
2. We will not be using WinRT/ARM but will stay on x86 for mulltiple reasons.
3. The device(s) will only need to be connected to the one app.

I've been told we either need to re-make the app for desktop with metroUI, but this will take too long. But based on my research here, I hear there is a possibility of developing custom device drivers that can give access to serial comms/virtual com port for a windows store app (that won't be released on the store).

my search finding were from over 2 years ago, so is this still the case? If so, can anyone point me in the right direction in regards to what needs to be done/guidance for doing so?

PS: Of course we had no idea that would be a problem at the beginning, as just never expected for MS to change things significantly like this.

Much appreciated.

Comment: Looks like non-trivial task. Did you think about writing a Windows service, which accesses serial port by standard Win32 way, and exposes some interface, which is not blocked for Metro UI applications, like IP sockets?

Comment: Did not consider that. We initially had the app developed externally but at completion were told that a core function; the Virtual COM Port would not work due to the limitations of Metro/Modern and its environment. So we're exploring all options. One option was to re-code for desktop, but we don't want to do that for obvious reasons. I was told developing custom drivers would be difficult as metro/modern (stupid name) as it restricts access to the Serial comms.